# How to install skype on CentOS without root access

Tags: linux, centos, skype, root

So I'm trying to install Skype on my office computer which has CentOS6.4 and where I have no root access. http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ only offers binaries for Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora and OpenSUSE. I tried the dynamic one, but it complains:

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The README recommends copying the skype binary to /usr/bin and installing sounds/, lang/ and avatars/ into the /usr/share/skype directory. Obviously I cannot do this, because I don't have root access.

Any other online CentOS installation guide always assumes root access.

I wonder: can it be done at all?

Comment: If you have wine installed, you could try to use the windows version of skype in wine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't have required 32-bit libraries.** If you have x86_64 arch CentOS installed you'll probably have to install some dependencies (i686 packages) for Skype using YUM.

Try searching for a package that contains that library `libasound.so.2`.

Example: `yum whatprovides libasound.so.2`

Output:

```
alsa-lib-1.0.22-3.el6.i686 : The Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA)
                           : library
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: libasound.so.2
```

Use that information to search for dependencies and then install.

Example: `sudo yum install alsa-lib.i686`

There'll be a few i686 dependencies for skype so you'll have to run Skype and resolve dependencies a few times before you get it to work. Good luck!

**PS. Without root access**, I don't think you have any chance

Comment: This seems like the correct answer (ldd confirms the lack of packages), accepted it and will upvote as soon as I have the reputation to do so :-). Also thanks for the PS, I think I will ask the sysadmins instead.

Answer (score 3):

You only have to unpack the .tar.bz2 into a folder somewhere in your home directory and run the `skype` executable.

If you have problems running it, try a different version (e.g. you could have another version than the one needed).

Comment: wont it still need a `chmod +x` ?

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn No. Since .tar.bz2 files preserve file permissions it is already executable immediately after unpacking.

Comment: good point. upvoting.

Comment: That's exactly what I did to get the above mentioned error message. Although it didn't make sense to me, I tried all the other versions as well, to no avail.

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen Sorry I missed this. Maybe you can try to download `alsa-lib-1.0.22-3.el6.i686` (which Ashtray suggested) using your browser. Extract it (e.g. by opening it and the `CONTENTS.cpio` in it with `mc`) and copy the libraries in question to your local skype directory. Maybe it works, but I think your chances are indeed very bad without root access.